# How to add Quartz Core Framework in new Xcode 3.2?

Tags: iphone, xcode

Since new Xcode 3.2 I find it very hard to add Quartz Core Framework. It does not appear in the list. Previously I just typed in Quartz and some QuartzCore.framework thing popped up. Finder is so bad it does not find any *.framework file on the mac so now the big question is: Where is it hidden?

Comment: Finder is not bad, spotlight doesn't look in the developer folders by default, only in user space and other common areas. A good way to find things is to drop into terminal, type "locate *.framework"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On the left side of XCode, there is a folder called `Targets`.  Expand it.  Double click on your target in that folder.  On the General Tab of the info pane that pops up, click the `+` sign on the bottom left corner of the window.  Scroll down and select `QuartzCore.framework`

You will also have to make sure your base SDK is 3.x

UPDATE: to use, place this import statement in your code
`#import <QuartzCore/CoreAnimation.h>`

Comment: Thanks. It seems like a horrible bug in xcode. Actually they promoted Xcode 3.2 to be a lot easier with adding frameworks. What a fail ;-)

Comment: coneybeare, can you also include the import statement for CATransition or CAAnimation as examples to make your answer more thorough?  I am trying to work on my code and design and continue to search for the logistical pieces :((