# Error in openflow library iphone

Tags: iphone, xcode

whenever I am adding an openflow library and execute, this error occur

```
Undefined symbols:
  "_CATransform3DIdentity", referenced from:
      _CATransform3DIdentity$non_lazy_ptr in AFOpenFlowView.o
     (maybe you meant: _CATransform3DIdentity$non_lazy_ptr)
  "_CATransform3DRotate", referenced from:
      -[AFOpenFlowView(hidden) setUpInitialState] in AFOpenFlowView.o
      -[AFOpenFlowView(hidden) setUpInitialState] in AFOpenFlowView.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Any one have any idea about it?

Comment: After having asked 21 questions already, please finally learn how to format on StackOverflow. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the "QuartzCore" framework to your app. The library you are using probably needs this framework, so your app needs to import this framework in order to compile.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to add the QuartzCore framework to your project. See [this question for Xcode 3.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566350/how-to-add-quartz-core-framework-in-new-xcode-3-2) or [this question for Xcode4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352664/how-to-add-existing-frameworks-in-xcode-4).