# Ios app and TestFlight integration

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, testflight

> I could not integrate the Test Flight sdk in my ios App for crash report.can some body help me to integrate the TestFlight sdk in my App in very simple steps.however i followed the TestFlight sdk documentation but could not integrate.

Comment: What's the problem? The docs are pretty straight forward, so what is difficult to you?

Comment: In step 2 (1)Select the Build Phases tab.
(2)Open the Link Binary With Libraries Phase
(3)If libTestFlight.a is not listed, drag and drop the library from your Project Navigator to the Link Binary With Libraries area.How to reach the build phase tab and Link Binary With libraries area.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Simple Steps are:

1] Copy The libTestFlight.a and It's header file in a folder and add that folder to your project

[image]

2] Make Sure your libTestFlight.a appears in linked binaries

[image]

3] Your Library Search path will have an entry such as

[image]

Finally Make a call to --

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [TestFlight takeOff:TESTFLIGHT_TEAM_TOKEN];
     //---- Other Stuff goes here 
}
```

Hope it helps !! You can find more resources on slideshare.

**EDIT: How to reach to linked Binaries Step - (Currently using XCode 4.3.3)**

**ScreenGrab**  - [image]

Comment: :thanks for the response but could you please tell me how i can do in xcode 3.2.6. Or please edit your answer step by step to do this Or can you please give the link of Slide share....I will be very thank full.

Comment: I am really afraid it's been ages now when I last used 3.2. But still can you share a screen shot for the Project and build settings - Just like the way I did. You can also catch me on chat :-)

Comment: This might guide you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566350/how-to-add-quartz-core-framework-in-new-xcode-3-2

Comment: :actually i have used xcode 3.2.6 but no longer now i am using xcode 4.2 and every thing is working fine

Answer (score 0):

Quick Answer:

Step 1 - [Download SDK](https://www.testflightapp.com/sdk/download/193/) and add it to your app bundle

Step 2 - Include libTestFlight.a in your linked frameworks and libraries (if its not there automatically)

Step 3 - #import "TestFlight.h" on your files that require test flight activity

Step 4 - Add the call to launch test flight in your application

```
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application 
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

//The Line you need
  [TestFlight takeOff:@"YOUR_TEST_FLIGHT_PASSCODE_HERE"]; 
}
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Note that Apple have [moved TestFlight to iTunes Connect](https://developer.apple.com/testflight/update/) and are [warning people to remove the framework from their products](https://twitter.com/simX/status/552912427369906176) so you shouldn't have to do this anymore.